# If there are two counter components to be tied to two properties in the Redux Store, do you have to write reducer, mapStateToProps, etc, twice?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

If on the React / Redux page there is already a counter component with the `+` and `-` buttons and a count in the middle, for `countNoodle` for the number of noodles ordered, and now, say we want to add the same counter for `countDrink`, do we have to write all the reducers, mapStateToProps, actions, connect, etc, one more time?

And when we add a `countSnack` counter, write all those lines one more time?

The Store state would look like:

```
{ countNoodle: 2, countDrink: 1, countSnack: 3}
```

So right now that Store only has `{ count: 0 }`. When it needs a counter tied to `{ countDrink: 0}`, then the following 50 lines of code has to be written once again (with `countDrink`, `increaseDrink` actions for Drink, etc)? And when `countSnack` needs to be added, another 50 lines of code?

I might have expected to be just one line, something like:

```
Instantiate(Counter, '#counterNoodle', store, 'countNoodle');
```

And actually, if we let the `Counter` use a local state, and let it pass the count back to the parent using a callback, we can achieve it by one line:

```
<Counter updateCount={updateNoodleCount} />
```

But if we use Redux, seems like we have to have a lot more code than that.

Right now this is the code for one counter:

```
// reducer.js
function reducer(state = { count: 0 }, action) {
    if (action.type === 'inc') {
        return { count: state.count + 1 }
    } else if (action.type === 'dec') {
        return { count: state.count - 1 }
    } else {
        return state;
    }
}

// Counter.js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

function Counter(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            { props.name }
            <button onClick={props.incCount}> + </button>            
            {props.countValue}
            <button onClick={props.decCount}> - </button>
        </div>
    );
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        countValue: state.count
    }
}

// Action

const incAction = { type: 'inc' },
    decAction = { type: 'dec' };

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        incCount: function () {
            return dispatch(incAction);
        },
        decCount: function () {
            return dispatch(decAction);
        }
    }
}

let connectedComponent = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Counter);

export default connectedComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you would right one reducer to increment and one reducer to decrement that receive the counter to be updated and then update the state of the corresponding counter. You would have to mapStateToProps for each counter though.

```
onClick={this.props.incrementCounter(countDrink)}
onClick={this.props.incrementCounter(countDrink)}


const incrementCounter(counterToUpdate){
    this.setState({ 
        ...state,
        [counterToUpdate]: this.state.[counterToUpdate] + 1
    })
}

const decrementCounter(counterToUpdate){
    this.setState({ 
        ...state,
        [counterToUpdate]: this.state.[counterToUpdate] - 1
    })   
}
```

In your parent component you could have 
`<Counter counter={this.props.countDrink} />
<Counter counter={this.props.countNoodle} />
<Counter counter={this.props.countSnack} />` 
The counter would receive a prop that you would pass depending on which item it was keeping count for.

Comment: is your `counterToUpdate` in `incrementCounter` a string, such as `"countDrink"`? If so, doesn't the code below has to be: `[counterToUpdate]: this.state[counterToUpdate] + 1`. You said "In your parent component you could have `<Counter counter={this.props.countDrink} />`" So you mean the parent is getting `countDrink` as a prop? What is `countDrink` -- is it a number, a component, or?

Comment: and it seems like if you don't use Redux, you could use `<Counter updateCount={updateNoodleCount} />` freely, no matter 1 time or multiple times, but if using Redux, you have to write the code to anticipate multiple counters in the page to begin with, in order to use multiple counters